# ValueError: Input 0 of layer max_pooling2d_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have checked all solutions, but I'm facing the same error all alon:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer max_pooling2d_4 is incompatible with the
> layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: [None,
> 1651, 298, 298, 10]

here is my code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(10, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation = "relu", input_shape=(1651, 300, 300, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
```

I checked every library and currently Im using the newest versions:

- Tensorflow 2.3.0
- numpy 1.16.4
- keras 2.3.1

If necessary: As IDE Im using Jupyter Notebook.

Beforehand I checked the shape of my dataset:

```
X_train = np.array(X_train, copy=True)
print(X_train.ndim)
print(X_train.shape)
```

> 4
> (1651, 300, 300, 3)

```
Y_train = np.array(Y_train, copy=True)
print(Y_train.shape)
```

> (1651,)

Comment: the correct input shape is input_shape=(300, 300, 3)... you don't need to pass the batch dim

Comment: Thank you. That was the issue.